# Undefined control sequence while using mathindent package

Tags: latex3

This is my **LaTeX Document** given below

```
\documentclass[16pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

    \noindent
    \textbf{\textit{$\underline{Integration}$}}
        
        \begin{equation*}
        \int{\frac{\log{|x^2+2|}}{(x+2)^2}dx}
        \end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The problem only occurs when I am using  **\mathindent** 
The error goes as follows:-

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \mathindent 
                   
l.3 \setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
```

Comment: Please revise the title you're not using any mathindent package here. Explain instead what you are trying to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\mathindent` is only defined if you load `amsmath` with the `fleqn` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\section*{Integration}

\begin{equation*}
  \int \frac{\log\lvert x^2+2\rvert}{(x+2)^2}\,dx
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Further notes.

1. There is no `16pt` option, only `10pt`, `11pt` and `12pt` for the font size.
2. Inputting math is simpler; many of your braces are useless and I have removed them.
3. `\lvert` and `\rvert` should be used for the absolute value.
4. If you *really* want boldface, italic and underlining (triple emphasis, note), it should be

   ```
   \textbf{\textit{\underline{Integration}}}
   ```

   without the `$` signs. But this is bad markup and should be avoided.